# How to apply sorting for specific column in jquery data table

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a `.cshtml` page where jQuery data table is created dynamically. There are 10 columns and sorting is working for 8 column, first two columns are not working.

I have taken value from model like below

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["OGWELLS"] as IEnumerable<PersonalPropertyCost>)
{
<tr>
<td class="table_heading text-right">                                                @Utility.FormattedLongValue(item.beg_value)
</td>
</tr>
}
```

And in utility.cs

```
public static string FormattedLongValue(long value)
{
   var formattedvalue = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,{0:#,###0}", value);
  return formattedvalue;
}
```

In database I have `beg_value` as integer, for e.g : beg_value is 1250 but after processing `FormattedLongValue()` method I am getting a `1,250` value.

But the problem is it is not sorted in jQuery data table. If I take only `@item.value` then only 1250 is displayed and sorting is enable.

But I want formatted value like 1,250 and it needs to sort on jQuery data table grid.

Please help me.

Comment: You can try using jquery datatables plugin - which adds sorting and filtering along with pagination and use to initialize the same as well.

Comment: I have already used jquery data table plugin but the problem is while passing integer data i need to format it and then pass to grid.

Comment: Can somebody please help me here to resolve this issue, I am trying to resolve this since last 4 day's. Advance thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get help from this.
1) http://live.datatables.net/oborug/2/edit
OR
2) You can do with your own logic not complex but trickiiiiiii.
   a) Get the values in object
   b) Remove the formatting,
   c) Sort the values
   d) Set the formatting
   e) Set the values to table.